# How to change values in unnamed first column

Tags: r

How do I change the entries of the first column in the matrix returned by `read_csv` if it doesn't have a header?

My variables currently looks like this:

```
                     PostFC       C1Mean
WBGene00001816 2.475268e-01   415.694457
WBGene00001817 4.808575e+00  2451.018711
```

and I'd like to rename `WBGene0000XXXX` to `XXXX`.

Answer (score 2):

If the first column is actually the rownames do the following

```
rownames(data) <- gsub(pattern = "WBGene0000", replacement = "", x = rownames(data))
```

If it isn't consistent, you may want to consider the stringr package and use the `substr` function

But if it is actually a vector with no header column, I do not know how to reference it without knowing the structure of the data.

run the `str` function of the data set and see what it returns. Or do the following as a test

```
 colnames(data)[1] <- "test"
```

Can't exactly help until we know how you have a "zero-length" variable name

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly the first "unnamed" column you describe are rownames and are not actually in you data.frame

```
# Example data 
df = data.frame(PostFC = c(2.475268e-01, 4.808575e+00), C1Mean = c(415.694457, 2451.018711) )
rownames(df) = c("WBGene00001816", "WBGene00001817")
df
# PostFC    C1Mean
# WBGene00001816 0.2475268  415.6945
# WBGene00001817 4.8085750 2451.0187

# change rownames
rownames(df) = c("rowname1", "rowname2")
df
# PostFC    C1Mean
# rowname1 0.2475268  415.6945
# rowname2 4.8085750 2451.0187
```

Comment: This works. Could you explain how assignment to `rownames` works? I have never seen an assignment to the output of a function before.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer this. Maybe post as a new question. If you want to circomvent the colnames step you could look into the csv file. maybe it is missing a colname in the upper left corner A1 in Excel or [1,1] in index. there might also be a way in the read_csv function to fore a new name upon import.

Answer (score 1):

The entries addressed are actually row names. We can access them with `rownames(.)`.

```
rownames(df1)
# [1] "WBGene00001816" "WBGene00001817" "WBGene00001818" "WBGene00001819"
# [5] "WBGene00001820" "WBGene00001821" "WBGene00001822"
```

In R also implemented is `rownames<-`, i.e. we can assign new rownames by doing `rownames(.) <- c(.)`.

Now in your case it looks like if you want to keep just the last four digits. We may use `substring` here, which we tell from which digit it should extract. In our case it is the `11`th digit to the last, so we do:

```
rownames(df1) <- substring(rownames(df1), 11)
df1
#           PostFC     C1Mean
# 1816  0.36250598  2.1073145
# 1817  0.51068402  0.4186838
# 1818 -0.96837330 -0.7239156
# 1819  0.02331745 -0.5902216
# 1820 -0.56927945  1.7540356
# 1821 -0.51252943  0.1343385
# 1822  0.47263180  1.4366233
```

Note, that duplicated row names are not allowed, i.e. if you obtain duplicates applying this method it will yield an error.

***Data used***

```
df1 <- structure(list(PostFC = c(0.362505982864934, 0.510684020059692, 
-0.968373302351162, 0.0233174467410604, -0.56927945273647, -0.512529427359891, 
0.472631804850333), C1Mean = c(2.10731450148575, 0.418683823183885, 
-0.723915648073638, -0.590221641040516, 1.75403562218217, 0.134338480077884, 
1.43662329542089)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1816", 
"1817", "1818", "1819", "1820", "1821", "1822"))
```